# IntelliJ: changing color of an unused variable

Tags: intellij-idea, color-scheme

How do I change the color of `unusedField` or an unused variable in IntelliJ? In `Color scheme` when I click on `unusedField` nothing happens. I was expecting IDEA to show me the default color settings (or show where it is derived from) but nothing happens. The screenshot illustrates the situation when I click on `unusedField`.

[image: screenshot of the Color Scheme settings]

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Just edit the color after "Foreground" in the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you know how I can decrease its shadow, but keep its original color ?

Comment: It's called "unused code" today, but resides in the same menu

Answer (score -1):

It's under "Settings/Editor/Color Scheme/General". You should select "Errors and Warnings/Unused code" and change the foreground color, marked with a red border on this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of the Settings/Editor/Color Scheme/General setting]